# Name 'lime_tabular' is not defined - ML Package

Tags: python, machine-learning

I already referred the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939447/name-is-not-defined),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447366/name-is-not-defined),and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679820/name-is-not-defined). So, don't mark it as duplicate

I am trying to execute a tutorial as provided [here](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/machine-learning/how-to-use-lime-to-understand-sklearn-models-predictions) (binary classification of breast cancer)

When I execute the below piece of code, I get an error as shown below

```
explainer = lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(X_train, mode="classification",
                                              class_names=breast_cancer.target_names,
                                              feature_names=breast_cancer.feature_names,
                                             )

explainer
```

> NameError: name 'lime_tabular' is not defined

But my code already has the below import statements

```
import lime
import lime.lime_tabular
```

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving a name to the imported resource.

You can either use `lime.lime_tabular` when you are calling it on the code,

or change the second line of import to `from lime import lime_tabular`

The second approach would be the one I prefer when I code.

Comment: Thank you, but let's not stop there. What you have is a NameError, this means it is the mentioning of lime_tabular that is getting a mistake, not the existence or usage of the lime_tabular per se. If it was the module that was missing, it would be a ModuleNotFoundError. Maybe another attempt would be 'import lime.lime_tabular as lime_tabular'. If you have more info I can try to figure it out.

Comment: you are fantastic. I made a typo error. I missed letter `F` in `From`. I typed it as `rom`. Hence, it didn't work. But now it works

Comment: If you have time, can help me with this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984947/efficient-way-to-generate-lime-explanations-for-full-dataset