# Efficient way to generate Lime explanations for full dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

Am working on a binary classification problem with 1000 rows and 15 features.

Currently am using `Lime` to explain the predictions of each instance.

I use the below code to generate explanations for full test dataframe

```
test_indx_list = X_test.index.tolist()
test_dict={}
for n in test_indx_list:
    exp = explainer.explain_instance(X_test.loc[n].values, model.predict_proba, num_features=5)
    a=exp.as_list()
    test_dict[n] = a
```

But this is not efficient. Is there any alternative approach to generate explanation/ get feature contributions quicker?

Comment: From your previous question, I believe you are using lime_tabular Explainer on this snippet, correct? There are different explainers in lime that use explain_instance.

Comment: @Arson0 - Yes, correct. Am using tabular explainer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what the docs show, there isn't currently an option to do batch explain_instance, although there are plans for it. This should help a lot with speed on newer versions later on.

What seems to be the most appropriate change to get better speed is decreasing the number of samples used to learn the linear model.

```
explainer.explain_instance(... num_features=5, num_samples=2500)
```

The default value for num_samples is 5000, which can be much more than you need depending on your model, and is currently the argument that will most affect the speed of the explainer.

Another approach would be to try adding parallelization to the snippet. It's a more complex solution where you run multiple instances of the snippet at the same time, and gather the results at the end. For that, I leave a [link](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/), but really it's not something I can give a snippet right out of the box.

Comment: you mean in my above code, I just have to use `X_test.loc[:,2500].values for 2500 samples?

Comment: Did I understand that correctly? because if I give `num_samples=2500`, then what will I key in the data_row paramter of explain_instance function?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. No, you can keep the things running as they are, you only add the num_samples to what you have, and in this way, the predictor will use fewer data to explain the model, although in many cases this is fine.

Comment: exp = explainer.explain_instance(X_test.loc[n].values, model.predict_proba, num_features=5, num_samples=2500) This number is relative, you should change it, the smaller num_sample, the faster it will go, but if you put a very small number, the explainer won't know enough to explain properly. More num_samples = More time + More precise. Less num_samples = Less time + Less precise. You need to find the point where you get good speed but don't lose explanation.

Comment: So, it still has to be a for loop. I see...thanks, accepted

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the lack of a batch approach means you need to explain each one individually. Nevertheless, there is the possibility of running many explanations at the same time using parallelization. If you really require much more speed than decreasing num_samples ends up giving you, try using pooling mechanisms (parallelization), if it works it can increase the speed a lot, but it's not very simple to set up. Good luck @TheGreat ! Anything else hit me up.

Comment: Can help me with this related post if you have time?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646792/how-to-get-lime-predictions-vs-actual-predictions-in-a-dataframe